# org mode to capture new to do list

Tags: org-mode

I tried to create a new task from the Capture with C-c t,
but it prompt me with

```
* NEXT 
[2019-01-12 Sat 18:17]
```

I assume it should be

```
** TODO
```

How could I change the default behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior is:

```
** TODO 
   [2019-02-02 Sat]
```

To reproduce the default behavior, you can open emacs without loading your init file using `emacs -q`, then use `M-x org-capture` and `t`.

Search in your init file for `org-capture-templates` to see if you configured your [t]-template wrongly . You can customize it using `org-capture` `C` or setting `org-capture-templates` this way:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("t" "Todo" entry (file+headline "~/org/gtd.org" "Tasks")
         "* TODO %?\n  %i\n  %a")))
```

See https://orgmode.org/manual/Capture-templates.html for reference.